# Warning: Attempt to present <CustomViewController> on <UINavigationontroller> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

*I know this has been asked a million times, but I couldn't find a suitable answer in those many questions that I've examined.*

I have a custom view controller, and I'm trying to display the view controller when the user taps a button (so no "infamous `viewDidLoad` problem" here).

Here is my code that runs when the user taps the button: (I have the NIB for the view controller, and I have a navigation controller)

```
ICLoginViewController *loginViewController = [[ICLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ICLoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
//assuming we have a navigation controller.

UINavigationController *navigationController= (UINavigationController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;
[navigationController.topViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I'm getting the `Warning: Attempt to present <ICLoginViewController: 0xa08a810> on <UINavigationController: 0xa45de70> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` error when I try to present the view controller. Nothing happens on screen. If I tap multiple times I get the same error, and still nothing happens. I've set a breakpoint and verified that `navigationController` and `navigationController.topViewController` are not `nil`. I' using storyboard (if it helps) but not for the custom view controller that I'm trying to display. (I want to make it an app-independent library in the long run, so I'm not referencing any app-specific modules within) Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why not to use self.navigationController?

Comment: yes I do. I have this code in a separate file which will be app-independent, and there `self` in this context is just an `NSOBject`-derived custom class, not a view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was, my modally displayed view controller was not the 'top' view controller in navigation controller. If I change the calling view controller to be pushed instead of being modal, then it becomes the top view controller and my app works well. Apparently, this had nothing to do with my custom view controller, but my navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

If its in an NSObject create a method inside the NSObject that takes your current viewController as an argument and present it there.
eg:

```
-(void)presentInViewController:(UIViewController *)controller{
    ICLoginViewController *loginViewController = [[ICLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ICLoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [controller presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:^(BOOL comp){}];
}
```

This way you can call that view controller wherever you want instead of trying to find your way through the navigation stack from UIApplication.

Comment: i don't want to deal with presenting the view controller from app. it will just call a login method, and my library will display a login view controller if appropriate (read: user is not logged in or access token is invalid). i've encapsulated the custom view controller inside my framework (at least, practically), i don't want the user to access the view controller directly.

Comment: You still need to present the view controller from another view controller that's on screen.. From looking at your error the controller you're presenting upon isn't actually on screen at the time. Using that method above and putting it in the NSObject you've created you should be able to block out the view controller they're trying to access with the login controller.

Comment: yes I've just figured out that my modal view controller (where I'm calling this method from) is not equal to the top view controller. if I change it to push segue, then everything is solved and my top view controller is the current one. I don't know why this is happening though..

Comment: Maybe try navController.visibleViewController instead of Top. Its hard to gauge the requirements for the nav stepping since I don't know how your app is structured.

Comment: yes, I've just changed it to that. my view controller is displayed correctly, and then the app crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS... I'll try enabling zombies now.

Comment: yep, it was a retaining error with my own class, corrected it now. nothing to do with view hierarchy.